# Treehouse or CodeSchool?

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks

I want to expand my JS/jQuery + PHP skills + frameworks, so question: Is it worth to buying some kind premium account to learn, if yes where threehouse or codeschool?

UPDATE:
I have inspected what course each website has, and I had decided to buy premium account at CodeSchool, because I like there AngularJS and other advanced web tutorials. Because on the Treehouse there were courses for those people who is starting from the beginning.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it worth it? In simple words, nobody knows.
This really boils down to what you want. PHP is a great language and you can find almost everything you want to know by googling, though it is nice to know the basics of the language.
I personally learnt PHP by sort of self learning (I watched online videos of Harvard university's courses on EdX(CS50). Google taught me the rest)

To simplify, if you want to go straight to the learning with ease, go for it. If you want to take your time, look around and see related stuff, learn yourself. Getting a project that challanges you is really useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already taught myself a lot @ codecademy. But now I want to expand my knowledge. Anyway thank you, I think I decided to choose CodeSchool

Answer (score 3):

I had a terrible experience with Treehouse, Why? Because it is focused to people with no experience with coding, I a knew php very well, so I learned nothing, but if you are starting with coding from 0 I would suggest Treehouse, they have a very good platform.